# How to dynamically render jsx with objects values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`Data` is an array object. I want to render table columns dynamically according to data object. I used this same technique to generate table head its working. Is there any way to fix this issue?

```js
const DataTable = ({data, deleteHandler, loading, tableFields}) => {

    const thead = [];
    const tbody = [];

    const [values, setValues] = useState({});

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tableFields)) {
        thead.push(<td>{value}</td>);
    }

    data.map((field) => {
        for(const[key,value] of Object.entries(field)){
            tbody.push(
                <tr>
                    <td>{value}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        }
    })

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Card className={classes.__bk_admin_card}>
                <Table borderless hover className={classes.__bk_admin_table}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {thead}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {tbody}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>

            </Card>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: You forgot to actually state your problem, it appears as though you're creating a new row for each "cell" in your data rather than creating each row and then appending cells to each row. The process should be pretty much identical to what you did for your header, only, there's an additional nested loop and a temporary `row` that you need to store for each row that you can push to your tbody array.

Comment: yeah i did that but its giving me an error.

Comment: Errors are useful for solving problems. They are simply a step along the way of getting the solution you want.